# How to use data value to refer back to another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use create a converter by using the data attribute to refer back to a previous value.

I cannot seem to get:

- data-my_currency to refer back to 301.46
- data-this to refer back to 4259.00

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var BTC = 4259.00
  var ETH = 301.46
  var LTC = 67.72

  var USD = 1
  var EUR = 0.83
  var CNY = 6.46

  var convertFrom = $('.js').data('my_currency'); 
  //Should refer back to EUR var
  
  var convertTO = $('.js').data('this'); 
  //Should refer back to BTC var
  
  var amount = $('input').val();
  var result = convertFrom * convertTO * amount;



  var newresult = result.toFixed(2);
  $('.output').html(newresult);



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="js" data-my_currency="EUR"></div>
<div class="js" data-this="BTC"></div>
<input type="text" class="input" />

<div class="output">Me</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively and without changing your existing code much, you can declare your variables at global scope (which you should avoid) and use `window` object to get the value of the variable.

```js
var BTC = 4259.00
var ETH = 301.46
var LTC = 67.72

var USD = 1
var EUR = 0.83
var CNY = 6.46

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function () {
        var convertFrom = $('[data-my_currency]').data('my_currency');
        var convertTO = $('[data-this]').data('this');
        var amount = $('input').val(); //Assuming user enters only numbers
        var result = window[convertFrom] * window[convertTO] * amount;
        var newresult = result.toFixed(2);
        $('.output').html(newresult);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js" data-my_currency="EUR"></div>
<div class="js" data-this="BTC"></div>
<input type="text" class="input" />

<div class="output">Me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to make them refer back to the JavaScript variables, why not simply use those JavaScript variables directly?

If, however, you have your Bitcoin and currency prices written as an element in the page (which is what I assume is the case), you're looking for `$('.js[data-my_currency]')[0].innerHTML` and `$('.js[data-this]')[0].innerHTML` respectively.

Breaking this down:

- `.js` targets the class `js`
- `[data-my_currency]` targets the [**attribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) `data-my_currency`
- `$('.js[data-my_currency]')` returns a [**nodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)
- `[0]` grabs the first node
- [**`.innerHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) grabs the content inside of that node.

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var convertFrom = $('.js[data-my_currency]')[0].innerHTML;
  var convertTO = $('.js[data-this]')[0].innerHTML;
  var amount = $('input').val();
  var result = convertFrom * convertTO * amount;
  var newresult = result.toFixed(2);
  $('.output').html(newresult);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="js" data-my_currency="EUR">0.83</div>
<div class="js" data-this="BTC">4259.00</div>
<input type="text" class="input" />

<div class="output">Me</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: EUR…may change to CNY or USD… the above code is nice… but it will not work for all currencies across the world.

Comment: You didn't specify that as a constraint. The code targets `data-my_currency`, so as long as `0.83` correlates to the value to exchange, it doesn't matter what the currency is. If you need to showcase multiple exchange rates at once, simply loop over the nodeList.

Comment: It should only convert one at a time… based on data-my_currency… Html EUR currency will change based on users drop down choice. So it will only run based on that one

Comment: So you'd like the `input` field to correlate to a drop-down, which would give options like `EUR`, `CNY`, `USD`, and correlate each to their JavaScript value? Rather than a direct input for the amount?

Comment: no… the question was just the converter part… their is also a drop down that choose between EUR, USD, CNY… etc. But I didn't put that part into the question. It wasn't needed

Comment: It wasn't needed? You **specifically** complained about me only covering one currency of yours. Please create a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and **clearly** state **exactly** what functionality you want.

Comment: Ok… sorry you did not understand the question… but someone else answered it in like 10s after your first post.

Comment: Check the answer above yours… Phani Kumar M answered it with no additional comments needed… thank you for your time.